# Dotnet pack - Resulting package has no dependencies

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, nuget

I'm trying to use an Azure-Devops pipeline to create and update a nuget packaget that depends on Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.

If I manually create the package using Nuget Package Explorer than I can add that dependency, but when I set up the Azure pipelines job to pack and publish the nuget package, it is created with no dependencies listed and therefore doesn't automatically install the necessary packages when included in a user project.

I've looked and the dotnet pack command documentation and it seems like this should be automatic, and all other questions are related to this issue are about project references, not package references.

the YAML I am using for this is beyond simple

```
    steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: GPIO/ProjectThatNeedsJSON.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you observed `no dependencies listed`. Here is my pipeline to pack and push my demo project for your reference, where we can see the `Newtonsoft.Json` was restored during `dotnet pack` step and the dependency was listed after being pushed to Azure Artifacts feed.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNet Pack
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byPrereleaseNumber'
    majorVersion: '1'
    minorVersion: '0'
    patchVersion: '0'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNet NuGet Push
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '$(TheProjectName)/$(ProjectScopeFeed)'
- script: tree /F /A
- publish: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
  artifact: drop-$(Build.BuildId)
```

[image]

**Program.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace DotNetConsoleAppDemo
{
    //After running the console will close so please add a breakpoint or sleep to see output.
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Example of serializing an object to JSON
            var myObject = new { Name = "John", Age = 30 };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
            Console.WriteLine(json); // Output: {"Name":"John","Age":30}
            // Example of deserializing JSON to an object
            string jsonToDeserialize = "{\"Name\":\"Alice\",\"Age\":25}";
            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonToDeserialize);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {deserializedObject.Name}, Age: {deserializedObject.Age}"); // Output: Name: Alice, Age: 25
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DotNetConsoleAppDemo.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```